# Media query optimization

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query written but it breaks at certain point, I am now trying to optimize the query to the following :

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (min-width: 1280px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1024px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 640px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 320px) {

}
```

Here is the one which i am using now

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: 3%;

    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 30px;
        }


    .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .span_of_2 {
        padding: 3% 0;
        margin: 4% 0;
    }
    .menu li {
        margin: 6px 16px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

       .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: 3% !important;

    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 25px !important;
        }
        .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .menu li {
        margin: 6px 12px;
    }
    .booking_room h4 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .booking_room p {
        font-size: 0.8125em;
    }
    .f_nav li {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: 3% !important;

    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 17px  !important;
        }

    .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .menu li {
        margin: 10px 8px;
    }
    .menu li a {
        font-size: 0.8725em;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_3 {
        width: 14.33333%;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .f_nav li a {
        padding: 0 0px;
    }
     .grid1_of_3 {
        float: left;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: -3% !important;

    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 9px  !important;
        }

    .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .row .grid_3 {
        float: right;
        width: 38.333333% !important;
    }
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
        .logo img
{ margin-left: -14% !important; }
    .h_right {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    .row {
        width: 70% !important;
    }
    .top-nav {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px 0;
        z-index: 999;
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav a{
        display: block;
    }
    .reservation ul li {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .booking_room {
        float: none;
        width: 98%;
    }
    .reservation {
        float: none;
        width: 98%;
    }
    .b_room {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .grid1_of_3 h4 a {
        font-size: 1.4em;
    }
    .copy {
        float: none;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .f_nav {
        float: none;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .soc_icons {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    .content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0%;
    }
    .sidebar {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 0%;
        border-left: none;
    }
    .sidebar h4 {
        margin: 4% 0 4%;
    }
    .sel_room {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .sel_room.left {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    .service_list li {
        width: 48.3333%;
        margin-bottom:4%;
    }
    .service_list li:nth-child(3){
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .reservation h5 {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
        .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: 3% !important;
    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 8px;
        }
    .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .logo{
        width: 20%;
    }
    .h_right{
        width:100%;
    }
    .row .grid_3 {
        width: 70.333333% !important;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .row .grid_3 {
        width: 70.333333% !important;
    }
    .book_date input[type="text"] {
        width: 96% !important;
    }
    .reservation ul li.left {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_2 {
        width: 49.33333%;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_3 {
        width: 47.33333%;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .grid1_of_3 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    .grid1_of_3 h4 a {
        margin: 2% 0;
    }
    .grid1_of_3 img{
        margin-top:4%;
        width: 10%;
    }
    .online_reservation {
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_2 {
        width: 48.33333%;
    }
    .res_btn form input[type="submit"] {
        width: 50% !important;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .contact_left {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .contact_right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .logo img{
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px) {
       .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: -11%;
                width: 70%;
    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 15px;
        }
    .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .logo{
        width: 32.333333%;
    }
    .h_right{
        width:60.333333%;
    }
    .row .grid_3 {
        width: 70.333333% !important;
    }
    .online_reservation {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .date_btn {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    .logo img{
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    .menuTemplate3
    {
        margin-top: -11%;
                width: 70%;
    }
        .menuTemplate3 a 
        {
         padding: 0 15px;
        }
    .wrap{
        width:95%;
    }
    .logo{

        width: 38.333333%;
    }
    .h_right{
        width:60.333333%;
    }
    .row .grid_3 {
        width: 70.333333% !important;
    }
    .reservation {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 97%;
    }
    .booking_room {
        width: 97%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .hide{
        display: none;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .reservation ul li.span1_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .book_date input[type="text"] {
        width: 93% !important;
    }
    .soc_icons ul li {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .grids_of_img {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .grids_of_para {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    .span2_of_1 {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    .res_btn form input[type="submit"] {
        width: 60% !important;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .service_list li {
        float:none; 
        margin-left:0;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
    }
    .contact-form input[type="text"], .contact-form textarea {
        width: 93% !important;
    }
    .contact-form input[type="submit"] {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 50% !important;
    }
    .logo img{
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with the use the optimized media query? I am confused to place the classes.

Comment: why was it voted down ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `max-width` and `min-width` both for media query like [this is example](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use both min and max widths to optimize:

```
@media (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1366px) { 

}
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) { 

} 
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {   

}
@media (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 768px) {   

}
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 640px){     

}
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 320px) {    

}
```